# Help with notation in logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

In propositional logic I know that if I have a set of atomic formulas $S=\{A_1, . . . ,A_n \}$

That an assignment $A$ of $S$, designates truth values to each of the atomic formula in $S$,

But is there some kind of generalization or extension of this word 'assignment' in predicate logic, like say I have the propositional function,

$P:(\text{X likes Y})$

And I wanted to assign values to the propositional variables ${x,y}$.

What would I call this assignment of variables?

Comment: Are you looking for [Interpretation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretation_(logic))?

Answer (score 3):

One term that is used is *valuation*. It comes up in one of the standard ways to define what is meant by a sentence of the language $L$ to be true in a particular $L$-structure $M$.  Formally, a valuation is a function from the set of variable symbols to the underlying set of $M$.

Comment: Can you give me an example using this word, how would I write that a specific valuation corresponds to a specific propositional function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *semantics* specifications in Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0122384520) (2nd - 2001), page 83 :

> let $\varphi$ a formula in the (*first-order*) language $\mathcal L$, $\mathcal A$ a *structure* for the language and $s : Var \mapsto |\mathcal A|$ a function from the set $Var$ of all variables into the *universe* (or *domain*) $|\mathcal A|$ of $\mathcal A$.

We may call $s$ a *assignment* function for the variables.

The "basic" clause of the *semantics* consists in defining :

> what it means for $\mathcal A$ to satisfy $\varphi$ with $s$;

in symbols :

> > $\mathcal A \vDash \varphi[s]$.

The informal version is :

> $\mathcal A \vDash \varphi[s]$ if and only if the translation of $\varphi$ determined by  $\mathcal A$, where the variable $x$ is translated as $s(x)$ wherever it occurs free, is true.

In conclusion, the "extension" to predicate logic of the concept of assignment of truth-values to the propositional letters of a propositional formula (which we may call *truth assignment* or *valuation*) is that of *interpretation*, made of a *structure* for the language and an assignment function for the variables.